# Writing multithreaded code to generate incremental index

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, algorithm

I want to write a code in following scenario :
we want to design an invoice generator.this invoice generator also generates an incremental invoice no .Also note that for some reasons we dont use something like sql Auto Increment here and we want to use C# (I wrote the increment logic). since several users can send requests at a time it means that we dont have to give the same invoice no to them (I used lock for it and I wrote it).

Now i have written increment logic. and i take care of multiple users requests with lock . and I wrote CRUD for mongodb database.

My problem is that my increent logic is naive. each time i find maximum and i increment by one which is not scalable. and another problem is that when we delete a record we don't want the invoice no to be repeated and since we find max if the deleted record had the max value then the invoice no would be duplicate and this is something we don't want to have.

I really don't know how to handle the problem. specially in case of deletion
should i store max values in a file or should i change increment logic completely?

i appreciate any help

Comment: Look up the `Interlocked` class, particularly `Interlocked.Increment`. You're on your own for persistence, particularly if you use an _eventual  consistency_ database

Comment: thanks for your answer. interlock.incremet handles multiple requests from multiple threads ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _requests_. It does the increment _atomically_. N threads can access the code and each will increment it by 1, and each will get a different result. I'm pretty sure the compiler manages the acquire-release semantics properly. Mostly _It just works_. You may want to look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/december/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice

Comment: What do you mean you find the maximum? The maximum from where? You can absolutely constrain this on a single server, but what happens if you need to run this implementation from multiple servers?

Comment: I would suggest using a database sequence for this. That will take care of the generation and persistence. Unlike an identity, sequences are independent of tables and thus don't rely on a record being inserted to generate a value. I don't use MongoDB but I would assume that it supports sequences.

Comment: thank you really for your suggestion of using Interlocked. it works really great. @Flydog57